# Quarkus best way to provide beans from library

Tags: shared-libraries, quarkus

I want to provide quarkus beans from a separate codebase, brought in as a dependency. What is the best way to do this?

My first thought was to find the artifact that has the annotations such as `@ApplicationScoped`, etc and making them part of my library dependencies, but after some searching it isn't obvious of the correct dependency.

I have also seen extensions, but making an extension feels fairly heavy; I don't need to change how Quarkus runs, just define some beans in a library.

I wish I could provide more in this question, but unsure of best-practice-wise where to go from here.

Comment: Asking for the "*best*" of something is opinion-based and therefore off-topic. --- I really see only one way: writing a producer method as described in the [Quarkus introduction to CDI, §13](https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi#ok-you-said-that-there-are-several-kinds-of-beans).

Answer (score 2):

Besides using a producer method, as said by @Turing75, you may enable bean discovery by generating a [Jandex Index](https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-reference#how-to-generate-a-jandex-index) for your library:

> A dependency with a Jandex index is automatically scanned for beans.
> To generate the index just add the following to your pom.xml:
>
> ```
> <build>   
>   <plugins>
>     <plugin>
>       <groupId>org.jboss.jandex</groupId>
>       <artifactId>jandex-maven-plugin</artifactId>
>       <version>1.2.2</version>
>       <executions>
>         <execution>
>           <id>make-index</id>
>           <goals>
>             <goal>jandex</goal>
>           </goals>
>         </execution>
>       </executions>
>     </plugin>   
>  </plugins> 
> </build>
> ```